# Possible to announce IPs through AWS?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ip-address, amazon-vpc

I'd like to have additional IPs with my EC2 instances so I'd like to lease IPs from a 3rd party since Elastic IPs seem to be far more expensive.

This would require me to announce the IPs.

Is it possible to announce leased IPs through AWS and how could I do that?

Comment: You only pay for Elastic IP addresses if you are *not* using them.

Comment: You say I could have 2000 elastic IPs and I would only pay for them if they are not attached to an instance?

Comment: You are not charged for the first EIP associated with an instance.

If you attach subsequent EIPs to the same instance, you are charged for those. If you have allocated EIPs are they are not associated with instances, you are charged for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do it. You can only route Amazon IPs to AWS instances.